# How to avoid duplicates in nested document while updating

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

My data model looks like this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBekf.png), also shown here:

```json
  {
    "_id": "619f6735336c8d0498bb5d00",
    "name": "Class 1",
    "department": "CS/IT",
    "area": "Engineering",
    "organization_id": "6192364e2983630e30df536a",
    "instructors": [
      "6198ca01d68ab59a877c4060"
    ],
    "individuals": [],
    "sessions": [
      {
        "sessionName": "Java",
        "topics": [
          {
            "topicName": "OOPs",
            "_id": "619f676e336c8d0498bb5d25",
            "subTopics": []
          },
          {
            "topicName": "Polymorphism",
            "_id": "619f676e336c8d0498bb5d26",
            "subTopics": []
          },
          {
            "topicName": "Objects",
            "_id": "619f676e336c8d0498bb5d27",
            "subTopics": []
          }
        ],
        "_id": "619f676e336c8d0498bb5d24"
      },
      {
        "sessionName": "JS",
        "topics": [
          {
            "topicName": "React js",
            "_id": "619F678b336c8d0498bb5d2f",
            "subTopics": []
          },
          {
            "topicName": "node js",
            "_id": "619f678b336c8d0498bb5d30",
            "subTopics": []
          },
          {
            "topicName": "Express js",
            "_id": "619f678b336c8d0498bb5d31",
            "subTopics": []
          }
        ],
        "_id": "619f678b336c8d0498bb5d2e"
      }
    ],
    "__v": 0
  }
```

If i have data like:

```json
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "sessions": [
      {
        "sessionName": "Java",
        "topics": [
          {
            "topicName": "OOPS",
            "subtopics": ["one"]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

I need add subtopic `"two"` in `"sessions"("Java")`-> `"topics"("OOPS")`->`"subtopics"` if the `"subtopics"` doesn't contain `"two"`. (Don't want duplicate there)

I tried `"$addToSet"` but

There is a difference in replication. (This can be seen if by taking a look at `local.oplog.rs`)

`"$push"` operations (that actually modified the array) are replicated as `$set.items.INDEX: item`

`"$addToSet"` operations (that actually modified the array) are replicated as `$set.items: [THE_ENTIRE_ARRAY]`

If you are dealing with large arrays, then the difference might be significant

so i'm afraid, it would affect the mongodb performance. any other solutions?

Comment: I edited your question to include your example document in a code block - it's not fun starting from an image.  Please don't use images for code, data, errors, tracebacks, etc. - just copy/paste them into a code block.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you are trying to do, you can use [`"arrayFilters"`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/) with `"$addToSet"`.

```js
db.collection.update({
  "_id": "619f6735336c8d0498bb5d00"
},
{
  "$addToSet": {
    "sessions.$[sName].topics.$[tName].subTopics": "two"
  }
},
{
  "arrayFilters": [
    {"sName.sessionName": "Java"},
    {"tName.topicName": "OOPs"}
  ]
})
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/RqH1ZJd1_aE).